# Look for inactive time frame in personnel activity table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am working on a SQL query that looks at personnel activity of more than 90 mins in that datetime field. Is there an easy way to query that?

So for example, If employee '1544' is inactive for 92 minutes, I am would just be looking for a return record of Employee ID, total inactive minutes and Date time of start and end of inactivity.

I understand then when off duty they will be inactive for more than 90 minutes so maybe just look for inactivity between 90 mins and 180 minutes?

```
SELECT        dbo.Personnel.ID AS Personnel_ID, dbo.Personnel.Emp_Name, dbo.Activity_Log.Date_Time AS Activity_TimeStamp, dbo.Activity_Log.Activity, dbo.Activity_Log.Terminal
FROM            dbo.Activity_Log INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Personnel ON dbo.Activity_Log.Personnel_ID = dbo.Personnel.ID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Response_Master_Incident ON dbo.Activity_Log.Master_Incident_ID = dbo.Response_Master_Incident.ID
WHERE        (dbo.Personnel.ID = 1542) OR
                         (dbo.Personnel.ID = 1544) OR
                         (dbo.Personnel.ID = 1545) OR
                         (dbo.Personnel.ID = 1546) OR
                         (dbo.Personnel.ID = 1547) OR
                         (dbo.Personnel.ID = 1548) OR
                         (dbo.Personnel.ID = 1549) OR
                         (dbo.Personnel.ID = 1550) OR
                         (dbo.Personnel.ID = 1551) OR
                         (dbo.Personnel.ID = 1552) OR
                         (dbo.Personnel.ID = 1553) OR
                         (dbo.Personnel.ID = 1554) OR
                         (dbo.Personnel.ID = 1555) OR
                         (dbo.Personnel.ID = 1556)
```

Comment: FYI [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Comment: Some better use of whitespace and line breaks would really not go amiss either here.

Comment: Tip: `id in (1542, 1544, ..., 1556)`.

Comment: Encourage others to help you. Provide a script or fiddle that includes consumable information and also provide your expected output based on the information. Think carefully - what if a person is inactive multiple times? And it seems a bit suspicious to filter based on the time value alone of a datetime column. Shouldn't an "inactive" period be based on a specific date?

Comment: I work in a 24hour dispatch facility. During the evening hours no admin personnel is there, just the dispatchers. So that's why I am only looking for inactive times just during the overnight hours. My supervisor just wants a report once a month looking for any instances during that month when someone is inactive for more than 90 mins.

Comment: I am a SQL novice. I just did a created a view using the tables I needed and thats where the query came from. I will take everyone's advice and clean it up. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Your question ***implies*** that you're looking for personnel where there is a gap of atleast 90mins between their activity records. Please edit your question to add example data demonstrating that, and include the exact results you want for that example data. [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) Pay particular attention to corner cases; what if the inactivity starts or stops during working hours, what if the inactivity is because they've finished work, what if it spans midnight, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question boils down to:

> How do I calculate the number of minutes between the current time and another time?

Once you figure that part out, I think you can work out the details.

Here's an example of how to calculate the number of minutes between two times in SQLServer:

```sql
-- Find the number of minutes between now and '2022-05-19 6:00'
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, GETDATE(), '2022-05-19 6:00')
```

I like to start with a very simple example until I understand how a new function works.

Using this in your situation might look like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM activity
WHERE DATEDIFF(minute, GETDATE(), activity.date_time) > 90
  AND userid IN ('io', 'europa', 'gannymede')
```

edit: After reading the OP's notes, this answers the wrong question.  Use `LEAD()` like @MatBailie suggests.

### Using LEAD (the right way)

Here's an example of using the `LEAD()` or `LAG()` function - my SQL is pretty rusty so you should really consult some other resources:

```sql
-- Create a temp table to play with.  
-- I'm bad with datetime stuff so I'm using an int to deomstrate the timestamp  
CREATE TABLE #activity ( 
    username varchar(50), 
    ts int 
    ) 

INSERT INTO #activity (username, ts) 
VALUES  
('io', 0), 
('io', 10), 
('io', 11), 
('io', 101), 
('io', 121), 
('europa', 35), 
('europa', 55), 
('europa', 86), 
('europa', 300), 
('europa', 400) 

SELECT username 
    ,ts this_ts 
    ,LAG(ts)  
        OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY ts) AS last_ts 
    ,ts - LAG(ts)  
        OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY ts) AS inactive_time 
FROM #activity
```

Which returns this:

| username | this_ts | last_ts | inactive_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| europa | 35 | NULL | NULL |
| europa | 55 | 35 | 20 |
| europa | 86 | 55 | 31 |
| europa | 300 | 86 | 214 |
| europa | 400 | 300 | 100 |
| io | .. | .. | .. |

Comment: The question implies that "the other time" is not fixed, but is actually relative to the datetime in the subsequent activity record; Using LEAD() rather than GETDATE()

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM Activity_Log
WHERE DATEDIFF(minute, LEAD(), Date_Time) > 90
  AND Personnel_ID IN ('1544', '1545', '1546')`

Comment: @chip I tried the above and got this error. "Msg 10755, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
The function 'LEAD' takes between 1 and 3 arguments."

Comment: @JustinNettleton,  `LEAD()` is a window function which is going to look completely different than `GETDATE()`. I added an example to the answer to get you started